# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key givenName

Tags: iphone

SO i have this

```
- (void)loadView {
BOOL success;
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSString* documentsPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* databasePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ProxDeals.db"];
NSError *error;

BOOL fileExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
if (fileExists==TRUE) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProxDealsViewController" owner:self options:nil];
}
else {
    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"ProxDeals.db"];
    NSLog(@"%@",defaultDBPath);
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:databasePath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@/.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"UserRegistration" owner:self options:nil];
}
```

}

and this error:

```
 Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ProxDealsViewController 0x5f22160> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key givenName.'
```

I know that i don't do something wright in the initialization of the UserRegistration nib but i don't know how to fix this.

Comment: It worked until i started to connect IBOutlets in the second class.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

This usually means that something is trying to access the @property "givenName".

If you were doing something with IB, the usual cause is that you either:

- deleted that property from the class,
  but haven't deleted the hookups in IB
  yet
- OR: you have a File's Owner
  object set to the wrong class (check
  the properties - different depending which version of xcode you're using - to find the Class Name
  its set as. You probably copy/pasted a NIB file, and didn't change this field in the NIB), and you've hooked up an
  outlet for that class, but your
  actual File's Owner is something
  different

Comment: I had a different problem that gave the error and your clear general guidelines helped me find the solution. A left-over hookup was fouling things up.

Comment: Apple really ought to consider improving their error messages.

Comment: well gotta be careful on copy pasting next time

Comment: Great man, that's what I did.

Answer (score 4):

This issue usually appears when there is a mismatch between the `IBOutlet`s in the NIB file and the .h file.

Make sure that you do not have any broken connections in IB (they usually appear with yellow and a warning sign next to them). Also, clean the project (Product > Clean in XCode 4) before building, you may have a stale compiled file.

Comment: I don't have any broken connection in IB.

Comment: I managed to make it work.I just declared the IBOutlets in the main class and set the FileOwner to the same class. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

It also happened to me after I had removed a UI element from the nib file and the corresponding IBOutlet from the view controller. Cleaning the project didn't solved it either.

Therefore I removed the folders within the DerivedData folder which is created by Xcode 4. Then it worked!

Answer (score 2):

If you have different storybord files and if you have outlet references with out outlets creation in your header files then you just remove the connections by right clicking on files owner.

Files owner->Right click->remove unwanted outlet connections over there.
clean and run your project

Go through this for clear explanation. This class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, it is very annoying to remove the app from the device/simulator, especially when you have saved data and configuration.

To solve this issue, for every `ViewController` for which you removed the `.xib`, file add the following code:

```
-(NSString*) nibName
{
    return nil;
}
```