# Any time I use an outlet to connect to a label, my app crashes

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, crash

No crashes until I connect the label. Any type of connection results in this:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x8d66200> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key
```

Classes are hooked up in each View Controller.

What is going on?!

Comment: just disconnect and reconnect connection ...

Comment: Please check this:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3088059/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458129/this-class-is-not-key-value-coding-compliant-for-the-key-givenname

Comment: @Piyush I read that. My classes are all connected to each other.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to set your custom class name in the XIB file (or one of the sections in the storyboard).  It is still the default (`UIViewController`).

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately I changed that and it's still not working.

Comment: You missed one (or one remains stale, be sure to clean and reinstall your app).

Comment: Do I need to change it on every view controller? Even the ones that don't have the label in them?

Comment: Changed it in every view controller. Still not working. I don't understand. :(

Comment: I don't know what to tell you.  The message is very clear.  You are trying to set an unknown value on a **UIViewController** object, not a controller of your class.  Without pictures and some code that's all I can say.

Comment: Those are all of the pictures you need.

Comment: Alright, now next.  When does this happen?  As soon as the app launches?  When you push a button?

Comment: Yes. Actually, when I select a cell.

Comment: Then show the relevant code that you use when you select the cell.

Comment: I have used a segue in my storyboard to link the view controllers.

Comment: Crashes when I click on the cell. Segues to the next view controller if I delete the label outlet.

Comment: Well, as I said earlier, first clean and reinstall your project.  Then if it still happens then you will need to analyze your storyboard and code to see if there is any possible place you are calling UIViewController instead of TerminalsViewController.  That's all I can tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Check references of your outlets in your `XIB`, one of the outlets is probably referencing a property that does not exist anymore

Comment: Nope. That is the only outlet.

Comment: @Eduardo Show a picture of your XIB.

Comment: @borrrden The storyboard? Why?

Comment: Well, this will sound bitter but I don't trust people on SO to tell or know the truth about what they are doing, so I want to see picture proof.

Comment: Wait scratch that, I know what is going on!

Answer (score 0):

[image]

> In above image lblserverDateTime is not exist in  outlet .So remove this
>   type of IBoutlet..

Comment: I only have one label connected and it does not have that.